# Cannot enable comments on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing my first WordPress site and started the process by developing on a local server via MAMP, using the theme "nine". All worked well and I was able to enable comments on all pages.

After I tried to migrate from MAMP to live server, without succeeding, i decided to create the website on the live server from scratch, which is not a big job as the website is not that big.

However I am not able to enable comments on all pages, BTW this is not a blog, and i am stuck.

I have been reading all kinds of things on internet but not succeeded and really need help.

Here is a few screenshots on some of the details that i think is important, they are in Swedish i am afraid.

Below is the page.php file:

```
<?php global $data;

get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-wrap">
<?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/slider' ); ?>
<div id="page-body" class="page-body">
<div class="container"><?php

    get_template_part( 'framework/inc/titlebar' ); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12"><?php
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>><?php
                    the_content();
                    wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
                </article><?php

                if(!$data['check_disablecomments']) {
                    comments_template();
                }

            endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My understanding is that i may have to add "" somewhere in this code.

Here is a few screenshots (Swedish) of, what i think, important pages:

[image: Dicussion properties]

++++

[image: Page discussion property]

++++

[image: Panel property]

Comment: can you name the plugin you are using?

Comment: @Anju Raghunath http://themeforest.net/item/nine-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4784524

Comment: check whether you have unchecked "Allow Comments" in admin(page listing section)

Comment: Do you mean on the panel tab that is on top - right? If so, yes it is checked. That should be the last picture above in my post, "Kommentarer".

Comment: try after removing that "if" from your code.(just need to see whether its because of disablecomments )

Comment: @Anju Raghunath I took away the "if" around the "comments_template();" and now i get comments on all pages :-) However, i now tested to disable it, as there is two pages that should not have comments, and that did not work. Still have comments on all pages after uncheck comments.

Comment: @Anju Raghunath a BIG thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anju Raghunath I was able to solve this problem by updating the page.php and add:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

after the:

```
"endwhile; endif; ?>" line.
```

See below in the updated page.php:

```
<?php global $data;

 get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-wrap">
<?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/slider' ); ?>
<div id="page-body" class="page-body">
<div class="container"><?php

    get_template_part( 'framework/inc/titlebar' ); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12"><?php

            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>><?php
                    the_content();
                    wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
                </article><?php

                if(!$data['check_disablecomments']) {
                    comments_template();
                }

            endwhile; endif; ?>
            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```